# Basic Math Operations with ImageMagick & CMD

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, cmd, imagemagick

I want to crop a picture multiple times. The postion where I need to start cropping depends on the equations:

```
startX = %x * 1024
startY = %y * 1024
```

I`m unable to implment that in a command line. This is what I got:

```
FOR /L %y IN (0,1,5) DO  
FOR /L %x IN (0,1,5) DO  
convert fireball.png -crop 2048x2048+(%x*1024)+(%y*1024)% fireball_(%x,%y).png
```

I'm using Windows 7 CMD.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your syntax but I can't vouch for your algorithm.  The % after the ) may be a typo but if it needs to be there then in cmd it needs to be doubled (as shown) to equal one %.

Note that CMD math is integer only and tops out at 2^31 - 1

```
FOR /L %%y IN (0,1,5) DO (
FOR /L %%x IN (0,1,5) DO (
convert fireball.png -crop 2048x2048+^(%%x*1024^)+^(%%y*1024^)%% fireball_^(%%x,%%y^).png
)
)
```

Comment: Actually, I think I need to set another variable = to %%x*1024 and use that variable as the parameter in the command.